# How to get params from query object in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, object, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

How do I get the 'params' from a query object in CakePHP 3?

```
$response = $this->getTable()->find();
// there are beforeFinds...etc that make this more complex
```

When I debug the `$response`, I get this (:

```
// ...
'(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
'sql' => 'SELECT .... WHERE ... article_id = :c2',
'params' => [
    ':c0' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ],
    ':c1' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ],
    ':c2' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ]
],
// ...
```

I'd like to know what the value of `:c2` is, but I can't seem to get the `params` to debug.

I've tried these:

```
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response->params);
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response->params());
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response['params']);
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response->getParams());
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response->getQueryParams());
```

But none work.

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the depth of the debug, I was able to see dditional information, including the values of the `:c2`

```
\Cake\Error\Debugger::log($response, 'debug', 4); // default depth is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get them via `$response->valueBinder()->bindings()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__debugInfo()` method:

```
$result = $this->Pages->find()->where(['is_public' => 1]);

dd($result->__debugInfo()['params']);
```