# CakePHP 3 - access params of Query object

Tags: cakephp, orm, query-builder, create-table, cakephp-3.x

In CakePHP 3.x I can do this:

```
$Substances = TableRegistry::get('Substances');
$query = $Substances->find()->where($where_conditions)->select(['id']);
debug($query);
```

This will show me the Query object.

If I want to get the SQL string I can use `debug($query->sql());`. This will give me the SQL string with placeholders for any parameters, e.g.

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... in (:c0,:c1,:c2))
```

When using `debug($query)` I can see the values for `:c0`, `:c1`, etc:

```
'params' => [
    ':c0' => [
        'value' => (int) 47,
        'type' => 'smallinteger',
        'placeholder' => 'c0'
    ],
    ':c1' => [
        'value' => (int) 93,
        'type' => 'smallinteger',
        'placeholder' => 'c1'
    ],
    ':c2' => [
        'value' => (int) 845,
        'type' => 'smallinteger',
        'placeholder' => 'c2'
    ],
    ':c3' => [
        'value' => (int) 354,
        'type' => 'smallinteger',
        'placeholder' => 'c3'
    ]
]
```

However, I cannot access them outside the `debug` statement. For example `$query->params()` or `$query['params']` doesn't give me the parameters - it will error. I want to be able to pass this array to a custom function, so how can I access it?

It's strange because I can use `debug($query->sql())` to get the SQL string as above, and `params` is just another thing in that object, but doesn't seem to be accessible.

I've read [How to get params from query object in CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602025/how-to-get-params-from-query-object-in-cakephp-3) but think that's a different question as it was to do with not seeing the values in the `debug` statement due to the default depth that `debug` would provide.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to do a `CREATE TABLE AS` query that will write the values of the `SELECT` statement into a new table (**Important:** see [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/tables/create_table_as.php) for an example of how that works in vanilla MySQL). I can't figure out how to do that with the ORM in Cake, so was planning on writing a custom function. But I need to be able to access both the SQL as well as the parameters bound so that the query can be executed in my own function.

If you know of a solution where I can use the ORM to do the `CREATE TABLE AS` query, I'm still interested to know about this. However I would like to know if `params` are accessible outside `debug()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP does not provide specific methods for creating such `CREATE TABLE AS` statements, so you'll have to build that on your own.

Compiling a query as the one shown in your question is simple enough using the query objects `sql()` method, and as arilia already mentioned, you'll be able to access the parameters bound to that query *after* is was compiled.

Having the compiled SQL and the associated value binder, you can combine this with a custom raw query to build your `CREATE TABLE AS` statement. All you need to do is prepare a new statement with the compiled SQL, and attach the value binder via its own `attachTo()` method.

One thing you might also have to do, is to define custom aliases in your `select()`, as otherwise you'd end up with columns selected (and created) in the form of `Substances_id`.

```
$Substances = TableRegistry::get('Substances');

$selectQuery = $Substances
    ->find()
    ->where($where_conditions)
    ->select(['id' => 'id']); // < create aliases as required

// compile the ORM query, this will populate the value binder
$selectSql = $selectQuery->sql();

// combine table creation SQL and compiled ORM query in a single statement
$createStatement = $Substances
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare('CREATE TABLE dynamic_table AS ' . $selectSql);

// attach the ORM querys value binder, binding all its values to the given statement
$selectQuery->getValueBinder()->attachTo($createStatement);

$success = $createStatement->execute();
```

This should create SQL similar to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dynamic_table AS 
    SELECT 
      id AS id
    FROM 
      substances Substances 
    WHERE 
      ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Interacting with Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#interacting-with-statements)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Association::attachTo()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.ORM.Association.html#_attachTo)**

Comment: This is excellent. Many thanks as always. I can confirm it works in Cake 3.5.13. +1 for the tips on creating aliases, that's quite important for what I'm trying to achieve later on in the application.

Answer (score 3):

Premise: I did not actually understand why you need the params

anyway. The information you need is stored by the query `ValueBinder` object

so you could simply do

```
$params = $query->getValueBinder()->bindings();
debug($params);
```

but for some reason this will get you an empty array. My guess is that the query need some kind of initialization first.

in fact if you run

```
debug($query);
$params = $query->getValueBinder()->bindings();
debug($params);
```

you'll see your params. I think someone more expert than me will come and give a full explanation

**edit:** I noticed that debugging `$query` calls `$query->sql()` which in turns calls `conection->compileQuery();`

so you can do

```
$query->sql(); // you need this to compile the query
               // and generate the bindings
$params = $query->getValueBinder()->bindings();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd already managed to navigate through Cake's code in NetBeans and found `getValueBinder()` but was having the same issue where it gave an empty array. Thanks for the tips. The reason I needed the SQL and it's params is because I want to execute the full "raw SQL" query in a custom model function. Because the SQL string (`$query->sql()`) just has the placeholders (`:c0,:c1,...`), I need to have the actual values so I can bind them with PDO so it will actually execute.